# Webpack 4: error with malformatted json

Tags: json, webpack

I'm using webpack 4 (4.6.0), I don't use the json-loader as it is my understanding that webpack handle this by default now.

When I'm working locally (I'm using serve from browser-sync to create a local dev-server), and I modified a JSON file wrongly (the JSON is not formatted correctly after my hcange), webpack **exit** with an error (instead of just telling me that there is an error on the json file and continue when I fix it).

**Anyone experienced this issue (and knows how to solve it)?**

This is the error I'm getting:

```
/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/JsonGenerator.js:10
    JSON.stringify(data).replace(
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at stringifySafe (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/JsonGenerator.js:10:22)
    at JsonGenerator.generate (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/JsonGenerator.js:36:53)
    at NormalModule.source (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:413:33)
    at ModuleTemplate.render (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/ModuleTemplate.js:43:31)
    at modules.map.module (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/Template.js:157:28)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.renderChunkModules (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/Template.js:154:28)
    at HotUpdateChunkTemplate.render (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/HotUpdateChunkTemplate.js:48:34)
    at compilation.hooks.additionalChunkAssets.tap (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js:165:48)
    at SyncHook.eval (eval at create (/code/program/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:17:12), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook [as _call] (/code/program/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at hooks.optimizeTree.callAsync.err (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:944:37)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/code/program/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/code/program/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at Compilation.seal (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:890:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:481:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/code/program/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/code/program/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:32:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:758:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/code/program/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:697:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

EDIT: Find below my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {},
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
    extensions: [ '.js' ],
    alias: {
      app: 'client/app',
      common: 'client/app/common',
      components: 'client/app/components'
    }
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')
  },

  mode: 'development';

  module: {

    rules : [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [ /app\/lib/, /node_modules/],
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: {
              failOnWarning: false,
              failOnError: true
            }
          },
        ],
      },
      {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
      ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [ path.resolve(__dirname, './client/app') ],
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [ /app\/lib/, /node_modules/],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ng-annotate-loader?add=true&single_quotes=true'
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.[ot]tf$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        ]
      }
    ],

    noParse: [
      '/node_modules/d3-cloud/build/d3.layout.cloud.js',
    ]
  },
  plugins: [

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      VERSION: JSON.stringify(require("./package.json").version)
    }),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      c3: 'c3',
      Bugsnag: 'bugsnag-js'
    }),

    // This is used to have a banner shown to the user to "Add to home screen"
    // It works with the service-worker called in app.js
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: './config',
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/')
      },
      {
        from: './assets/**/*',
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/')
      },
    ]),

    // Injects bundles in your index.html instead of wiring all manually.
    // It also adds hash to all injected assets so we don't have problems
    // with cache purging during deployment.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'client/indexMockBackEnd.html',
      //template: 'client/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      hash: true,
      favicon: 'client/app/common/favicon/favicon.ico'
    }),


    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      ENVIRONMENT: JSON.stringify('development'),
      BROCHURE_HOME_URL: JSON.stringify(`https://pl.dev`)
    }),

    // Adds webpack HMR support. It act's like livereload,
    // reloading page after webpack rebuilt modules.
    // It also updates stylesheets and inline assets without page reloading.
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    // displays desktop notifications on MacOS
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
  ],

  optimization: {
    namedModules: true, // NamedModulesPlugin()
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all"
    },
    runtimeChunk: true,
    concatenateModules: true //ModuleConcatenationPlugin
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show your webpack code?

Comment: @AlessanderFrança I've edited my question to add webpack config

Comment: This looks like a bug in webpack. There should be some sort of null check in the code the error is showing. Consider opening up an issue on the webpack repo?

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in webpack, I've open an issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in webpack.

See details of the bug here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7082

See pull request to fix it here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/7590

It is now fixed (as of July 2018)